# How to import from text file to sql server table having millions of records

Tags: sql-server, text, bulkinsert

I have a text file of coauthor data set containing author id's and number of co-authored papers separated by spaces. I want to import this data in sql server table whereas number of records in this text file is in millions i.e. of size 73MB of text file.
Please help out the way by which I can import this file to sql server table.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BULK 
INSERT yourtable
FROM 'location with filename'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

find more from here
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/775961/Import-CSV-or-txt-File-Into-SQL-Server-Using-Bulk

another [GUI approach](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2008/how-to-import-a-comma-separated-file-into-sql-server-2008/) can be useful.

Comment: The OPs data does not have commas!

Comment: FIELDTERMINATOR has been changed to space thanks @JohnS